# Do I need to use HTML form tag if there is no action?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a registration form, where the user needs to enter an email and a password. I know that in general this kind of forms are wrapped in an html form tag which usually has action attribute which sends the information from the inputs to the server and stuff like that. But in my case, I don't need to use any action attribute, because I simply take the information from email and password inputs and do my stuff with those values, such as checking if the email and/or the password are valid and proper, etc and then I send this info to Firebase realtime database. So, I use only Javascript/jQuery to grab the information I need and send it wherever I need which completely works for me.

My question is do I still need to put these inputs inside a form tag and not specify action attribute or specify an action attribute with the value of empty string or I can just put them in a div and do my stuff in a way I am doing right now. Is there anything wrong in the way I am doing this?

I read a few articles about html form tag and action attribute, but none of them answered to this specific question.

I think no code is needed

Comment: `<input>` elements (and other elements like that) do not have to be in `<form>` blocks.

Comment: if you didn't use **javascript** you really need `<form>`.

Comment: Using form also lets user submit using keyboard, has validity api and is better for accessibility

Comment: @I'mLimit so putting the inputs in a div and grabbing the info I need with jQuery is totally fine, right?

Comment: @Suren if you sure you set `listener` to all input

Comment: when user press **ENTER**

Comment: You could have gotten an instant answer by just reading [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) or test an example in [the validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use javascript to submit data the form tag **isn't mandatory**, but if include it not cause you problem maybe you can find it useful for some reason:

- if you want to attach ajax to submit action

```
var form = document.querySelector(',myform');

form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
  console.log('submitted');
  });
```

- or if you want to use some ready to use js validation library
- to serialize data
- ...

Use it if it isn't a problem, maybe you'll need it in the future.

Comment: Need to prevent default though

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything wrong in the way I am doing this?

besides potential accessibility hickups, less semantic markup, and no functionality for people who turn off JavaScript, not really =)...

depending on how you handle the inputs (e.g. `on('change', ...)`) and submitting the data to your backend for checking the user input you might benefit from having the from tag present because with it you can

a) listen for `submit` events and
b) serialize the entire form once it is submitted instead of having to collect each individual input

but that completely depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to put `input` in a `form` if there is no action to perform

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23637905)

Comment: @theTinMan This looks like a reasonable attempted answer to me (despite being unfortunately short and without elaboration)

Comment: Well, the `form` tag, in general, is used when there is some data to send to the server with a given HTTP method such as GET or POST and there is a button to `submit` the form. In this case the HTTP request is managed by the browser itself and there is no need to perform the request manually, using javascript. Another useful thing is that user can reset the form using an `input` of `type` equal to `reset`. Usually the form tag is used for server-side rendered pages that does not uses javascript to perform HTTP request to the server. @the

Comment: @theTinMan I hope this comment helps to better answer the question

Comment: Don't put the explanation in a comment. When you do that you force everyone to read every comment to understand the question and answers. Your information should be inside your answer to explain why you say that, so edit it and add it as if it'd been there initially; Don't put "Edited" or "Updated" tags as we can tell what changed because SO keeps a revision log. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work will help.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Single line answers automatically get flagged by the system for review because they're rarely considered to be adequate. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question helps explain the issues. The additional information in his comment will be excellent if he moves it into the answer.

Comment: @theTinMan Short answers are still answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387377/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379608/ Downvote if you like, but if it's a reasonable attempt at answering, they shouldn't be deleted from LQP https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/ An answer doesn't have to be a *great* answer to qualify for continuing to exist on the site

Comment: The selected answer in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387378/128421 is my attitude.